# ruby require very slow

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script running on an ec2 small instance running ubuntu 10.10 and ruby 1.9.2p0 (no rails)

I am requiring a few files on top and dying directly afterwards to test the speed. Two gems are taking a lot of time to load.

This is the list of gems i'm loading:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'
require 'json/pure'
require 'logger'
require 'aws'
require 'time'
```

running the file and dying right after the requires takes 2.3 seconds

without active_record it will run in 1.4 seconds
without aws it will run in 1.1 seconds

and without both aws and active_record it will run in 0.3 seconds

I am new to ruby coming from php and expected it to be faster. Are these load times normal or there's something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Might have to do something with this (rails example, but a ruby issue): http://rhnh.net/2011/05/28/speeding-up-rails-startup-time. Any reason you can't use 1.9.3?

Comment: @Thilo looks like the same issue. 1.9.2 is the the version that comes with the ubuntu version running on the server. will look into updating..

Comment: Agreed, upgrade to 1.9.3 if possible as load time is significantly improved.

Comment: That's about right -- on my computer running 1.9.3-p125 it takes 2.8 seconds to require all those gems. Keep in mind that requiring ActiveRecord also requires ActiveSupport. Both are pretty large libraries in Ruby-land.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p194 on 64-Bit Arch Linux and 
    require 'active_record'
takes about 1.5 seconds, so I think it's normal.